# Gradle task dependency order

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-plugin

I have a problem with a custom gradle task : i would like to copy my android jar library and rename it after that it as executed a 'clean build'
Here is how i defined it :

```
task('CreateJar', type: Copy, dependsOn: [':mylibmodule:clean', ':mylibmodule:build']){
  doLast {
    from('build/intermediates/bundles/release/')
    into('libs')
    include('classes.jar')
    rename('classes.jar', 'MyLib.jar')
  }
}
```

The problem is that in the gradle log results, the 'clean' is done after the 'build' task, so that the lib is never copied to the destination folder :

```
...
:mylibmodule:testReleaseUnitTest
:mylibmodule:test
:mylibmodule:check
:mylibmodule:build
:mylibmodule:clean
:mylibmodule:CreateJar NO-SOURCE
```

I have also tried to change the order of tasks in the 'dependsOn:[]', but it does not change anything... Does anyone has any idea of where is my mistake ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Why does creating a Jar depend on cleaning?

Comment: It may be an old bad habit when i was coding in C to always clean before building. The build creates an aar, but i just need the jar created in intermediates build directory. The CreateJar task is more an automatic copy that i want to be done during build in target directory

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `dependsOn` list does not impose any ordering guarantees. Usually what is listed first is executed first if there are not other relations that actually do impose ordering guarantees.

(One example is if `clean` depends on `build`, then it doesn't matter how you define it in that `dependsOn` attribute, becuase `build` will always be run before `clean`. That this is not the case is clear to me, thus in parentheses, just to clarify what I mean.)

To determine why finally `build` is run before `clean` I cannot say without seeing the complete build script. From what you posted it is not determinable.

Maybe what you are after is `clean.shouldRunAfter build` or `clean.mustRunAfter build` which define an ordering constraint without adding a dependency. So you can run each task alone, but if both are run, then their order is defined as you specified it. The difference between those two is only relevant if parallelizing task execution, then should run after means they could run in parallel iirc, must run after does not allow that.

Comment: Thank you for your answer; I was not sure for the 'ordering guarantees'. In fact, 'clean' and 'build' tasks are automatically managed by the android-gradle plugin, so i can not change their behavior.I'll need to analyze hox it is managed and maybe I'll have to try to make it another way

Comment: Sure you can. You can modify any task you want. If you want to add a `dependsOn` or a `shouldRunAfter` or whatever, you can just do it without any problems. Applying the plugin adds and configures the tasks and you can freely change them afterwards in your build script.